# Why can we assume that there is no constant value when doing a "reverse derivative" by going from a $v(t)$ equation to a $d(t)$ equation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to solve this question for my calculus homework on derivatives:

**A car whose position is given by the equation $d(t) = 25t + t^2$ passes a police car that is traveling at 20 m/s. The police officer turns on the siren and begins to accelerate at 1.5 m/s^2 to chase the speeding car.**

**a) At what time is the speeding car moving at 31 m/s?**

The derivative of $d(t)$ is $v(t) = 25 + 2t$, so the time is 3 seconds for the speeding car.

**b) How fast is the police car moving at that time?**

The police car's $v(t)$ equation is $v(t) = 20 + 1.5t$, so subbing in 3 seconds gives us 24.5 m/s.

**c) How far apart are the vehicles at that time?**

Here, I assumed the "reverse derivative" of the police car's $v(t)$ equation was $d(t) = 20t + (3/4)t^2$, and then I used the other speeding car distance equation as well. I plugged in 3 seconds into both of these and then I found that the distance between them is 17.25m which is right.

For part c), when we are going from the velocity-time equation to the distance-time equation for the police car, why can we assume that there is no constant value? If there was a constant value, how would we know what it is? Like what I mean by that is with this equation that models the distance of the police car, $d(t) = 20t + (3/4)t^2$, how do I know if it's not like $d(t) = 10 + 20t + (3/4)t^2$? But mainly, when and why can we assume that there is no constant value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually ill-posed, it doesn't say *at which time* the speeding car passed the police car and *from what point* the displacements are calculated. Your (and their!) solution apparently assumes that *they passed each other at $t=0$ and all the displacements were taken from the place where they met*. The problem statement should've been a lot more explicit about that.

With that assumption, the displacement of the police car is indeed:

$$d(t)=\int 20+\frac{3}{2}t\,dt=20t+\frac{3}{4}t^2+C$$

however the assumption that at $t=0$ (when they met) it was $d(t)=0$ yields:

$$20\cdot 0+\frac{3}{4}\cdot 0^2+C=0$$

i.e.

$$C=0$$

Comment: Yes, and I also have an issue with how "begins to accelerate" apparently means "undergoes constant acceleration".

Comment: @ryang True, although "begins to accelerate at $1.5\frac{m}{s^2}$", sort of, does imply constant acceleration. We also seem to be invited to imagine that the speeding car passed the police car, the police officer saw that, and began accelerating - all at the same time. These are also things which were not stated pedantically enough.

Comment: My own pet peeve is about *dimensionality*. How can it be $d(t)=25t+t^2$ when the left side is in metres and we add seconds and seconds squared on the right side? The correct writing is $d(t)=25\frac{m}{s}t+1\frac{m}{s^2}t^2$. However, this kind of sloppiness is so usual in the problems of this type that I have given up.

Comment: Eeeeps! (Hadn't noticed that till you pointed out.) And you're totally right; I retract my complaint: "at t=0, I start running at 8m/s", although technically consistent with "1 min later, I am running at 5m/s", is more reasonably construed as "t=0 is the start of my 8m/s constant-speed run". hehe